# WordPress check_ajax_referer gives 403 forbidden when using inside AJAX action

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, nonce

I am making an AJAX call in WordPress to connect an API. For this I am trying to use a nonce in order to prevent any unauthorized or robot access. This is my code:

**functions.php**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'yrc_cst_ajax_platform_script_enqueue');

function yrc_cst_ajax_platform_script_enqueue () {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'platform',
        get_template_directory_uri(). '/includes/platform.js',
        array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

    wp_localize_script('platform', 'yrc_cst_platform', array(
        'ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
        'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('platform_security')
    ));
}

add_action('wp_ajax_save_platform_contact', 'yrc_cst_save_platform_contact');
```

**Inside AJAX action method I wrote this (functions.php):**

```
function yrc_cst_save_platform_contact() {
   if ( check_ajax_referer( 'platform_security', $_POST['security'] ) ) {
      var_dump($_POST['security']);
   }
   ...
}
```

And here is the AJAX call:

```
jQuery.ajax({
   url: yrc_cst_platform.ajax_url,
   type: 'post',
   data: {
      action: 'save_platform_contact',
      security: yrc_cst_platform.ajax_nonce,
      contact_email: client_email
   },
   success: function(response) {
      // Doing my stuff...
   }
});
```

In the console I see this

> Failed to load resource. The server responded with a status code: 403
>   (Forbidden) /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

If I remove the block `check_ajax_referer(...)`, things are working OK. Everything is in my local. I am testing the cycle as a logged in user only.

I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of check_ajax_referer is used to specify where to look for nonce in $_REQUEST. When you call check_ajax_referer( 'platform_security', $_POST['security'] ) you basically tell the function to check on $_REQUEST[$_POST['security']].

You should use it like this:

```
check_ajax_referer( 'platform_security', 'security' )
```

You can read more about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_ajax_referer

Answer (score 2):

try using wp_verify_nonce instead of check_ajax_referer as below:

```
function yrc_cst_save_platform_contact() {
if ( wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['security'], 'platform_security' ) ) {
  var_dump($_POST['security']);
}
 ...
}
```